# App crashes with "isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted"

Tags: android

I have two classes `TrapCard` and `EquipmentCard`, from which I want to make an object and pass this object through activities. I put a string and a int variable into my parcelable object. The int variable is a reference to an `.svg` image. And then I'm trying to get the reference from the object to load the `.svg` image in another activity. For `TrapCard` this works. But when I'm doing the excat same thing for `EquiptmentCard` my app crashes with `E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted`

Constructor from `EquiptmentCard`:

```
public EquipmentCard(String cardName){
        this.cardName = cardName;
        switch (cardName){
            case "Rope": cardPicRes = R.drawable.ic_rope;
                break;
        }
    }
```

And here I'm trying to get the reference and load the image

```
final EquipmentCard equipCard = new EquipmentCard(cardName);
                            returnIntent.putExtra("card",equipCard);
                            returnIntent.putExtra("cardType","E");
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    imgViewCard.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(equipCard.getCardPicRes(), getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
                                }
                            });
```

Here same thing for `TrapCard`, this works

```
final TrapCard trapCard = new TrapCard(cardName);
                            returnIntent.putExtra("card",trapCard);
                            returnIntent.putExtra("cardType","F");
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    imgViewCard.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(trapCard.getCardPicRes(), getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
                                }
                            });
```

I'm doing this within the `receiveDetections` function from the Google mobileVisionAPI

with debugging I can see that my code runs to this line

```
imgViewCard.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(equipCard.getCardPicRes(), getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
```

and then crashes with the mentioned error in logcat.
I put this in try and catch but there is no error I receive. Thank you in advance for your time and have a nice day.
UPDATE1: I set the image in `EquipmentCard` to `ic_spider1` and it worked. I have no clue whats wrong with `ic_rope`.
UPDATE2: Now i get an exception `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable xxx.xxx:drawable/ic_rope with resource ID #0x7f060072` but i have no clue why. I added this the same way i added spider. Delete and adding again don't work.
UPDATE3: Alright. It seems that my `ic_rope.xml` has a large string inside. I tried to rebuild my Project and then it shows the message `string too large to encode using UTF-8`. If i delete the `ic_rope.xml` i can rebuild without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
imgViewCard.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(equipCard.getCardPicRes(), getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
```

with:

```
setImageResource(R.id.your_image_id)
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this, thanks. But why did this ```imgViewCard.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(equipCard.getCardPicRes(), getApplicationContext().getTheme()));``` work for ```TrapCard``` and not for ```EquipmentCard```? Shouldn't it work for both then?

Comment: mhm i don't want to use a thrid party library just for some images. there must be a way to work with the onboard tools? But when i found no way I'm gonna try this